# "This app could not be installed at this time" CFBundleIdentifier error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, cfbundleidentifier

I encountered the "This app could not be installed at this time" error. I have tried several methods such as reloading the simulator, deleting the app in the simulator and cleaning the Xcode project. However, it still has this error. I turned to the CoreSimulator file and found an error because of the CFBundle Identifier. Here is the log below:

```
Apr 26 18:49:49 kevins-air com.apple.dt.Xcode[27210] <Error>: installApplication:withOptions:error:: Error Domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain Code=1 "This app could not be installed at this time." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=This app could not be installed at this time., NSUnderlyingError=0x7faad5709050 {Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=12 "Bundle at path /Users/kevinlauofficial/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0EB4D69B-61C8-468B-9D3D-2D6761E1D9D6/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.IMKy1v/extracted/DBS.app/Frameworks/HandySwift.framework did not have a CFBundleIdentifier in its Info.plist" UserInfo={LegacyErrorString=MissingBundleIdentifier, FunctionName=-[MIBundle _validateWithError:], SourceFileLine=45, NSLocalizedDescription=Bundle at path /Users/kevinlauofficial/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0EB4D69B-61C8-468B-9D3D-2D6761E1D9D6/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.IMKy1v/extracted/DBS.app/Frameworks/HandySwift.framework did not have a CFBundleIdentifier in its Info.plist}}}
```

Sorry I couldn't turn it to code format. Here is a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of error]

DBS.app/Frameworks/HandySwift.framework did not have a CFBundleIdentifier in its Info.plist}}} shows that the HandySwift.framework did not have a CFBundleIdentifier in its Info.plist . What should I add to the property list?
Here is a screenshot of my Info.plist.

[image: info.plist]

Please help me fix this error, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have faced same issue. After long research find below solution. Please follow it, I am sure it will work for you.

**Solution: 1**

> Erase All content and settings.
>
> Clean your project

**Solution: 2**

> Changing the CFBundleShortVersionString in InfoPlist.strings to match
>   the one in info.plist fixed this for me. I had to use the simulator's
>   "Erase All Content and Settings" after making this change.

**Solution: 3**

> I deleted pods from project and installed it again and it surprisingly
>   works fine.

For remove pod file:

```
pod deintegrate
```

For install pod:

```
pod install
```

**Then run again your project.**

Comment: For me, 'deleting the derived data' and running project freshly has solved this issue

Comment: Solution 3 has solved the issue. Thanks! Clearing simulators and that kind of actions did not work as mentioned in other stackoverflow discussions.

Answer (score 2):

**Make Target membership tic-mark**

[image]

**Or** Uninstall your pod file  and reinstall pod file

Answer (score 2):

XCode: 11.3.1
Cocoapods: 1.9.1

None the previous solutions worked for me.

This should be related to the pod `info.plist` file setting. You might want to select Pods directory in the navigation panel of XCode and then set the info list files for each pod framework.

[image: Image - Correctly placed identity of each pod framework]

If there's anything goes wrong with this, there will be a button to choose the `info.plist` file.

Just click on that button and navigate to the bottom of the Pods directory from popup file dialog, and select your project’s `pods-info.plist` file.
It will automatically assign the correct identity for that pods framework like you see in the above image. This will solve the problem.

Comment: This solution really worked for me. I have to select info.plist for rach pod.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this problem. The reason why I meet this error is that I changed the bundle Id only the general of Menu of the project. You must also change it Test and UiTest too. After I change them, the problem is solved.