# Missing Info.plist value - A value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName'

Tags: ios, info.plist

Missing Info.plist value - A value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle 'test.comp.dev.pac-pen.watchkitapp'. Apps built with iOS 11 or later SDK must supply app icons in an asset catalog and must also provide a value for this Info.plist key. For more information see

Comment: You can check my answer for the same problem might be it's work in your case also :-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50041392/this-app-could-not-be-installed-at-this-time-cfbundleidentifier-error/50041507#50041507

Comment: its not the same . my problem is different

Comment: can post ss for that.?

Comment: there is no sreenchot that is the message apple have email me when i upload my app to app store

Comment: that things you have to mention in you question.this error happen when you upload on app store

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216718/missing-cfbundleiconname-in-xcode9-ios11-app-release

Answer (score 1):

Go to `File->New->File` and scroll down to add an `Asset Catalog` under the `Resource` header. Open your `Asset Catalog` and add images for the `AppIcon`.